# How to call Java Class from JSP page? Cloud9 & OpenShift JBoss

Tags: jboss, openshift, cloud9-ide

I am new to c9. I created a Openshift JBoss application server & imported into C9 via GitHub.
I have a simple Java class in Main\Java\initial.class.

```
public class initial {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String prn = disp();
        System.out.println(prn);
    }

    public static String disp()
        {
        String str=" JAVARANCH ";
        return str;
    }
}
```

I have a jsp page called from index.html, I am just trying to display the variable 'prn' in the jsp page.

```
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>JBossAS7 JSP snoop page</TITLE>
    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils,java.util.Enumeration" %>
    <%@ page import="java.lang.management.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@ page import="initial" %>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<H1>WebApp JSP Snoop page</H1>
<img src="images/jbosscorp_logo.png">

<h2>JVM Memory Monitor</h2>
<input type="text" name="text1" size="100" value="<%=prn%>">
```

But, I am getting below error at the JSP page:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file
The import initial cannot be resolved

    An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /snoop.jsp
    prn cannot be resolved to a variable
    12: <img src="images/jbosscorp_logo.png">
    13: 
    14: <h2>JVM Memory Monitor</h2>
    15: <input type="text" name="text1" size="100" value="<%=prn%>">
    16:  
    17: <table border="0" width="100%">
    18:
```

How do I interact with a Java class from my JSP?
thanks.

EDIT due to two answers:
I think the main issue is: the class 'initial' is not being imported successfully. My call to Prn was wrong, I understand that now, but the Import itself is not working.
some suggested having the class inside a package. But Cloud9 IDE does not have an option to create a package.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file
The import initial cannot be resolved
```

Comment: I'm not a big Java expert but I think that `prn` only exists within the scope of main, so if you called main inside your JSP that might display the string you're looking for. `disp` may also do it because it's also static.

Answer (score 1):

If you try this :

Java class:

```
public class Initial {

    public static String getDisp() {
        return "JAVARANCH";
    }
}
```

JSP file :

```
<HEAD>
        <TITLE>JBossAS7 JSP snoop page</TITLE>
        <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils,java.util.Enumeration" %>
        <%@ page import="java.lang.management.*" %>
        <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
        <%@ page import="Initial" %>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>WebApp JSP Snoop page</H1>
        <img src="images/jbosscorp_logo.png">

        <h2>JVM Memory Monitor</h2>
        <input type="text" name="text1" size="100" value="<%=Initial.getDisp()%>">
    </BODY>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access your class from your jsp by adding the following.

```
<input type="text" name="text1" size="100" value="<%= initial.disp() %>">
```

or by adding a jsp scriptlet prior to your input

```
<%    
String prn = initial.disp(); 
%>

<input type="text" name="text1" size="100" value="<%= prn %>">
```

Notice I am using your method **disp()** not **main()**.  Main is static void with no return.